# text to speech using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, readspeaker

I am using a service called read speaker from this link https://www.readspeaker.com/text-to-speech-demo/ for text to speech using the following code:

```
 fetch('https://tts.readspeaker.com/a/speak?key=xxx&lang=sv_fi&voice=Samuel&text=veta', {
            method: 'get',
            // headers: {
            //     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            // },
            mode: 'no-cors'

        })
            .then(response => {
                 console.log("RESPONSE: ", response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("ERROR: ", error);
            })
```

For some reason the response shows this:
**ERROR: No or invalid key specified** thou I am giving the right api key.

When removing method: 'POST' I get the following response:

```
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaque"
url: ""
```

I have no idea what to do or what is the issue!

Comment: If you signed up for a trial key, maybe you've already exhausted the number of requests? Anyway, this question is more suitable for the people at readspeaker.com, given the error message you're getting.

Comment: I agree with @ChrisG on getting help from the official support team through your account, especially since it looks like their documentation requires a login.

I can say though, that you are probably mixing up your request types. They probably require a POST request, but with the parameters sent through the body / as form-data. Your first example is a POST, but you are sending params as query string params.